# Custom launcher in application panel not working

Tags: launcher, .desktop

I have created an app launcher for `Eclipse JEE` and `Eclipse C/C++` with `alacarte`. The `.desktop files have been created and I dragged the apps via the dash board on the launcher panel. But when clicking on them nothing happens!?

Here the `.desktop` file of one of them:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=/home/dan/Programs/eclipse_c/CDT_icon.png
Name[en_US]=Eclipse C
Exec=~/Programs/eclipse_c/eclipse_c
Comment[en_US]=Eclipse C
Name=Eclipse C
Comment=Eclipse C
Icon=/home/dan/Programs/eclipse_c/CDT_icon.png
```

unil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `Exec` entry isn't executed by a shell you can't use `~/`.

Replace

```
Exec=~/Programs/eclipse_c/eclipse_c
```

with

```
Exec=/home/dan/Programs/eclipse_c/eclipse_c
```

Comment: Also make sure that the actual executable file can be executed. (e.g. chmod +x eclipse_c)